# PHP warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\hse\vendor\composer/../../app/Buildings.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've previously manually deleted some models files in App* and created other with just removing the "s" symbol as because laravel by default can recognise the models from there name , and models by Laravel standadrd must be written normal not in plural.

Before deleting the models that i created them using 
php artisan make:model Buildings -m

The new model i created after i removed the (buildings) model is 
php artisan make:model Building 
Notice that i just created a new model without 's'

Now in my User model i have created method :

```
public function UserAssignedBuilding(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Building','App\Area','user_id','area_id');
    }
```

Building.php Model file

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Building extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'buildings';

    public function areas(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
    }

}
```

Area.php Model file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Area extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','area_user','area_id','user_id');
    }

    public function buildings(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Building');
    }
}
```

In php artisan when i run the following command, to get the user assigned buildings:

```
>>> User::find(4)->UserAssignedBuilding
PHP warning:  include(C:\xampp\htdocs\hse\vendor\composer/../../app/Buildings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\hse\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

It seems that the error is the framework trying to load the (Buildings.php) model file, which i had already delete it and created (Building.php) instead .

I run the following :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\hse>composer dumpautoload
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

But issue not fixed

Also tried to get buildings rows, other error showing:-

```
>>> Building::all()
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Building' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your command you are missing model namespace

It should be

```
App\User::find(4)->UserAssignedBuilding
```

And

```
App\Building::all()
```

Also change method `UserAssignedBuilding` to `buildings`

Comment: >>> App\User::find(4)->UserAssignedBuilding
PHP warning:  include(C:\xampp\htdocs\hse\vendor\composer/../../app/Buildings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\hse\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 444
>>>

And second command :App\Building::all() is successfully retrieved all the buildings table records . But why when i use the same command without specifying the model namespace for (User::all() and some other tables ) i am getting a record successfully

Comment: Try to rename `UserAssignedBuilding` to `buildings` and use it like this `App\User::find(4)->buildings`

Comment: This worked , after i posted this question i've changed the method name to UserBuildings() so when i mentioned on my previous comment that the command still give the same error, i typed the old method name
App\User::find(4)->UserAssignedBuilding

But my question is : why some models can be called in tinker without typing there namespace

Comment: Not really sure why it works for some... maybe look [here for more info](https://laravel.io/forum/10-10-2014-how-can-i-use-user-class-without-namespace-like-laravel4-in-laravel5develop-branch)

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider accepting it. For  **why some models can be called in tinker without typing their namespace?** maybe create a new question

Comment: Same error showing , even i type the full namespace :
>>> App\User::find(5)->role
PHP warning:  include(C:\xampp\htdocs\hse\vendor\composer/../../app/Roles.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\hse\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php on line 444

The Roles.php is old model file that i've deleted it before

Comment: do you have [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#introduction) set up? instead of `->role` try `->roles`

Comment: Yes i am 100% sure that the relationship setup perfectly. The error showing is that composer class loader is trying to load a non exist old model "/app/Roles.‌​php" (Roles.php) ... this model is old and i have deleted it and created (Role.php) instead .
However i have created a new laravel project just for testing, and created two migrations (roles, users) , then created a model files with same relationship what i structured now , return me result without error :

Answer (score 6):

The error is showing in Tinker (php artisan tinker) ,
When i dumped the composer autoload file

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Then tried again in tinker , the same error is showing like the composer dump command did not do it work, but when i close the current tinker and open new one (php artisan tinker) , every thing now work perfectly .

So , the solution in brief is when you run the dumpautoload command, you need to restart the tinker to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but in my case the problem was case sensitivity of composer autoload.

I had created `user` class (with small 'u') using `composer artisan make`. So it created `user.php` file for me. Afterward, I decided I like `User` (with capital 'U') more, so I changed the class name but not the containing PHP file.

So the problem was composer was looking for `User.php` file instead of `user.php`. changing the containing file to `User.php` did the job for me.